# updated_at and created_at fields not inserted automatically while inserting into collections using InserGetId function?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, collections

I am using mongoDB, and while inserting data into a collections using **InsertGetId** but created_at and updated_at  fields are populating in mongo db collections. But for remainging collections i have used **insert** to put data into collection. So, for that i am getting updated_at and created_at timestamp. Why?
Please explain.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If we are using **Insert** or **InsertGetId** functions in order to insert data into collections. rather than that we can use **create** function, for this **create** function gets updated_at and created_at automatically for mongoDB.